# Extracting .ASPXAUTH cookie from Visual Basic Script

Tags: asp.net, vbscript, winhttprequest

I am creating an Excel Vbs script that is connecting to a ASP.Net application using Forms authentication. The connection works fine, the problem is that I am not able to extract the .ASPXAUTH cookie from it. Here is the script:

```
Sub GetAspCookie()

Dim objXmlHttpMain, URL
Dim strJSONToSend As String
strJSONToSend = "{""Username"":""myuser"",""Password"":""mypassword""}"

URL = "http://localhost/MySite/Account/Login"
Set objXmlHttpMain = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

On Error Resume Next
objXmlHttpMain.Open "POST", URL, False
objXmlHttpMain.SetRequestHeader "Connection", "Keep-Alive"
objXmlHttpMain.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"

objXmlHttpMain.Send (strJSONToSend)

strHeaders = objXmlHttpMain.GetAllResponseHeaders()

MsgBox strHeaders

'Both attempts below return empty cookie    
'strCookie = objXmlHttpMain.GetResponseHeader("Cookie")
'strCookie = objXmlHttpMain.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")

If Err Then            'handle errors
  WScript.Echo Err.Description & " [0x" & Hex(Err.Number) & "]"
  WScript.Quit 1
End If
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Here are my response headers showing up in my vbs message window:[image: vbs response headers]

The strange thing is that when I execute the same POST from POSTMAN I get this response which contains the .ASPXAUTH cookie inside of **Set-Cookie**:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /MySite/Home/Index
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-StackifyID: V1|b4e46c31-4679-4688-ae56-743d63cdc6fd|
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 5.2
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=4D423446F2578F5BC081006964A3909A4218E36C4D0A8E0F00D60D005606611F8783E2CBC0206438ABD603F08D1333C6E19C9AE3E92EB06580EFC19A43D31F4484F6534E598C7CB630DE3CA001BB4B3BBED300209EC103BCCA3E3ABA5AD3EC922D345CBC2135E4E6649056631C283EE3EF89A871D9DC7B3B...; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 10 Apr 2018 22:22:44 GMT
Content-Length: 454
```

Why is my WinHttpRequest not returning the Set-Cookie response header?